# how can i compare two consecutive iteration steps? in C++

Tags: c++, buffer, iteration

I built a program that is cyclic called. Each time value T changes, and I'd like to compare value T and T from previous cycle, and do it for every cycle.

```
int T = externalsrc; //some external source
int prevT; //cannot do it because in the first cycle it will have no value when used in comparison
int prevT = 0; //cannot do it, because in every cycle prevT will be zero for my comparison
int comparison = prevT - T;
prevT = T;
```

How can I do it properly then? I tried also this, but still T is not declared here:

```
int T;
int prevT;
if (prevT != T)
  prevT = 0;
else
  prevT = externalsrc;
int comparison = prevT - T;
prevT = T;
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is a code question. It appears that how to define the first value is entirely dependent on how these values are used, and we have no idea on that.

Comment: question is here actually how can I introduce a variable which will contain value T from the previous step. It will go well all the time apart from the first step, where there is no previous. I cannot initialize it to 0, because then in every cycle this program is called, prevT will be 0 in the equation. So I kind of lack algorithmic solution for it

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to save the value to a file and load it from it when you run the program next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your first answer, but declare `prevT` as `static` and init to 0:

```
while (condition) {
    int T = externalsrc; //some external source
    static int prevT = 0; // declaring static means that it will only be set to 0 once
    int comparison = prevT - T;
    prevT = T;
}
```

...that way on every subsequent iteration the initialisation of `prevT` is ignored, and the value is preserved from the last iteration.

Comment: Wrapping up this behaviour in a class would be much better than using a static.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a boolean variable to tell you if it's the first time or not.

Some thing like this:

```
bool first_fime = true;

// ...

if (first_time)
{
    // Do something with T only
    previousT = T;

    // It's no longer the first time
    first_time = false;
}
else
{
    // Do something with both T and previousT
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define prevT as `static` within your function.

Your code will be like this

```
int T = externalsrc; //some external source
int prevT; //cannot do it because in the first cycle it will have no value when used in comparison
static int prevT = 0; //The first time it is called it will start with pr
int comparison = prevT - T;
prevT = T;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct compare
{
    compare() { prev = 0; }

    int operator() (int t)
    {
        int cmp;
        cmp = prev - t;
        prev = t;

        return cmp;
    }
private:
    int prev;
};
```